# SharePoint 2010 audience issue

Tags: service-applications

run a powershell command for compling the audience(audience.exe xxxxxx 0/1) we receive the following error

ORGLE_Job_End =>close down the job, Application id=xxxx xxx xxx

Can't log into SQL, site=xxx xxx,  exception error=object not set to instance of an object

Thanks
P.Mohan

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint databases are pretty well locked down so only a few IDs can access them.  This sounds an awful lot like a case where the identity that the powershell command is running as is not one of the ones that can access the site.

If you are querying global audiences then you also need to make sure that the identity running the script has permissions at that level as well.  Or, simply run the script using an identity that you know has permissions.

Comment: Can you explain DB name and permssion details where i can give the permission Please assist US.please assist me

Comment: It is far easier to simply run the powershell script using an identity that you know has permissions, such as the application pool account.